# How to add a URL to a LaTeX bibtex file?

Tags: urls, bibtex

I'm using `bibtex` for my bibliography in LaTeX. I have some URL's I need to cite in the paper. How do I add URLs into the `.bib` file?

A typical section in my `.bib` file looks like this:

```
@conference{eigenfacepaper,
  title={{Face recognition using eigenfaces}},
  author={Turk, M. and Pentland, A.},
  booktitle={Proc. IEEE Conf. on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition},
  volume={591},
  year={1991}
}
```

I tried some misc sections in `bibtex` but they don't show up in my document.

Comment: Please have a look at this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36248/url-of-cited-web-site-in-bibliography/36255#36255

Answer (score 379, accepted):

The last time I cited a URL, I used a BibTeX entry of the following form:

```
@misc{bworld,
  author = {Ingo Lütkebohle},
  title = {{BWorld Robot Control Software}},
  howpublished = "\url{http://aiweb.techfak.uni-bielefeld.de/content/bworld-robot-control-software/}",
  year = {2008}, 
  note = "[Online; accessed 19-July-2008]"
}
```

If that does not show up, then it might indeed be a problem with your BibTeX style (or you forgot to `\usepackage{url}` or `\usepackage{hyperref}` in your main `.tex` file).

Comment: Don't forget to add `\usepackage{url}` in your tex file; doesn't work for me otherwise.

Comment: `\usepackage{hyperref}` is rather more powerful and flexible than `\usepackage{url}`.

Comment: Is it wise, or even appropriate, to use both? Or will they clash at some point?

Comment: Are double brackets in title usefull? Or typed there by mistake?

Comment: @koleygr I think they stop the automatic capitalization from changing the title (so BWorld stays BWorld and doesn't become Bworld)

Comment: A small python code for replacing `url` with `howpublished` and `urldate` with `note={Accessed: _original entry_}` in `@misc` sections| Link: https://gist.github.com/anant347/21ab974526f70328f4773b8f3e7cbbdc

Comment: Do we need to escape any characters, like `&`, `#`, etc. in the URL, when using this format?

Comment: This adds semicolumn after the url instead can we put `.` ?

Answer (score 76):

You need to

```
 \usepackage{url}
```

and then

```
 howpublished={\url{http://my.url.com/}},
```

Comment: This doesn't really fit into my bibtex file

Comment: Use hyperref instead of url package if links don't work due to linebreaks.

Answer (score 51):

Depends what BibTeX style you're using. In the ordinary ones I usually use

```
note={\url{http://...}}
```

in biblatex (and natbib too, I think), you can just write

```
url={http://...}
```

Comment: This actually helped solving my query https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565551/links-to-publications-in-bib-file-get-printed-as-plain-text-on-moderncv?noredirect=1#comment1425038_565551

Answer (score 19):

To use url with a `plain` bibliography style you can use this format:

```
@misc{Doe:2009:Online,
author = {author},
title = {Title of Citation},
year = {2010 (accessed December 7, 2014)}, 
howpublished = "\url{http://www.myurl.com}"}
```

Additionally you need to add the url package

```
\usepackage{url}
```

If you want to use the url attribute in you need to use natbib because standard bibstyles (such as plain) will not typeset the url key contents of the individual entries; it is required to use one of natbib's own entries, e.g. plainnat.

For example

```
@ONLINE{Doe:2009:Online,
author = {Doe, Ringo},
title = {This is a test entry of type {@ONLINE}},
month = jun,
year = {2009},
url = {http://www.test.org/doe/}
}
```

and the document

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{test.bib}

\title{BibTeX Website citatations with the \textsf{biblatex}~package}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\nocite{Doe:2009:Online}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Source: http://nschloe.blogspot.ro/2009/06/bibtex-how-to-cite-website_21.html

Comment: This would be better as a comment on the accepted answer.  Post it on gist.github.com (don't forget to add the `.tex` extension for syntax highlighting) and paste the link as your comment :)

Comment: Hi Sean. I really have to disagree with you on that. First Im not really only extending on the accepted answer but providing additional information and second I think it is bad practice to provide essential info in a comment. I think it is better to edit the original answer (if only extending a little when the answer is very popular) or provide a new one. In my case I compiled infos from different answers into a new one bc I think all of them do only tackle part of the question.

Comment: If the information is truly essentially helpful, then it would do more good as an edit to the vastly popular answer – it simply won't help anyone down here `:(` Additionally, this answer is self-contradictory – it doesn't use `natbib`, but rather the separate (and better IMO) BibLaTeX.

Answer (score 7):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you are trying to reference websites and not articles in a journal, for instance.  And, having placed said references in a `misc` entry, they don't show up when you reference them.  If that is correct, then the problem is your bibliography style (`bst` file) does not have an entry in it for dealing with a `misc` type.  I would suggest that you use [biblatex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) as it highly customizable and includes an `online` entry type specifically for your purpose.  Alternatively, you could use [custom-bib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/), which will give you a custom `bst` file that would display a `misc` entry.  However, I think [biblatex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) is still your best bet.

Comment: It would be most unusual for a bibliography style not to recognize the extremely common `@misc` entry type. In fact, such a style would have to be considered to be broken.

Answer (score 7):

The TEX FAQ used to have really good answers for TeX related questions: [URLs in BibTeX bibliographies](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-citeURL):

```
@misc{...,
  ...,
  howpublished = "\url{http://...}"
}
```

Comment: https://www.bibtex.com/f/howpublished-field/