# Bibtex entry with URL

Tags: bibtex, urls

I want to cite some lecture notes in my thesis where the main and only source is a webpage (including some PDFs which are the lecture notes).

I am using Bibtex.

I tried `@webpage`, like:

```
@webpage{CAVR112,
    Author = {Rajeev Alur and Thomas A. Henzinger},
    Date-Added = {2012-07-10 03:24:13 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2012-07-10 03:30:02 +0000},
    Institution = {MTC EPFL},
    Lastchecked = {2012-07-10},
    Title = {Computer-Aided Verification},
    Url = {http://mtc.epfl.ch/courses/CAV_WS2004/},
    Year = {2004}}
```

in my bib-file but that gave me the warning `Warning--entry type for "CAVR112" isn't style-file defined` and the URL was not shown in the bibliography section (`\bibliographystyle{alpha} \bibliography{bibliography}`).

I also tried `@misc` but the URL is also not shown. As the URL is quite important for this source, I want to have it shown but I'm not sure what bibtex entry type I should use.

---

Just found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35977/how-to-add-a-url-to-a-latex-bibtex-file) very related question. It works by using `howpublished = {\url{...}}`. Not sure if I should close this as duplicate or if my other questions are relevant (e.g. I'm still not sure about the entry type here...).

Comment: In addition to the provided answers, if your bst do not support url and you are forced to use that bst, you can use the field `note`, as for example: `note = {\url{...}},`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.ctan.org/pkg/urlbst has a collection of bibtex styles that have support for webpage, url and lastchecked entry types.

the bundle also provides a script that will edit an existing .bst to offer those entry types.

the incidental text in the styles is in english (herbert's suggested styles are in german).

Answer (score 3):

http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/BibTeX/

has BibTeX style files which know the entry type `url= {...}` for
article, book, aso
Save one of the styles into your local $TEXMF, eg `/usr/local/texlive/texmf.local/bibtex/bst/` and run `texhash`. In your document use `\usepackage {url}` if you do not load `hyperref`