# @webpage fields in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex

For a BibTeX `@webpage` entry, what fields are mandatory, and what fields are optional? I've tried to Google for an absolute reference for this, but can't seem to locate one.

Comment: Related: [Bibtex entry with URL](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62793/bibtex-entry-with-url)? Please look at this link. If this does not answer your question, then please tell us.

Comment: @hpesoj626 I don't think it answers my question about mandatory and optional fields, or does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@webpage` is defined by the package [urlbst](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/urlbst). You can also type `texdoc urlbst` in your terminal to open the manual.

The required fields are `title` and `url`. The optional fields are `author, editor, note, year, month` and `lastchecked`.

You can find the details in `page 3` of the `urlbst` manual.