# bibtex display URL in reference

Tags: bibtex, urls, ieee-style

I am trying to display a URL in a reference using the bibliography style ieeetr. According to  [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35977/how-to-add-a-url-to-a-latex-bibtex-file) I can use the `howpublished` field in my bibtex entry, but it seems that this doesn't work for me. Here's my bibtex:

```
@Manual{XXXX,
title = {Title},
author = {Paul},    
Note = {version 1.6.0},
howpublished = {\textit{Available at \url{http://www.qqq.com}}}
}
```

and here my `tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\section{A}
Citation:  \cite{XXXX}.
 \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{vignette}
\end{document}
```

The bibliography looks like this after pdflatex and bibtex:

```
[1] Paul, Title. version 1.6.0.
```

but no URL. Does anyone see what could be the problem?

By the way, unfortunately I cannot use `biblatex` because the compilation must be running on multiple computers with standard latex installation.

However, I would be open to other bibliography styles if this would be a solution!

Comment: did you try the normal url field ? @misc{stefano2012,
 title = {{„Shitstorm“ ist Anglizismus des Jahres 2011}},
 url = {http://www.anglizismusdesjahres.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/adj2011-pressemitteilung.pdf},
 urldate = {2013-05-25},
 author = {Stefanowitsch, A.}, 
 month = {february},
 year = {2012}

Comment: The bibliography style chooses which fields to put in each entry of the bibliography. It seems that the `howpublished` field is not included for `manuals`. How about just putting the url in the `note` field?

Comment: @Dukeatcoding: I tried the `url` field, but this does not work either.

Comment: @JohnWickerson: I did this before, but it seemed a bit dirty to put both information in there (version and URL). If I have two note fields one gets ignored. However, if there is no easy way around this I will just put version and URL in the note field.

Comment: maybe you try a different ieee style ==> \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,mybibfile}, that defenitely support an url. ftp://tug.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf

Comment: @Dukeatcoding Thanks, this seems to work. However, I had to install extra packages on my Ubuntu for this style and my latex should be compilable on any standard linux box, so I will do as suggested by John Wickertson

Comment: @JohnWickerson Care to write an answer? Maybe adding what Dukeatcoding added

Comment: @percusse Done `:)`

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The bibliography style – `ieeetr` in your case – is responsible for choosing which fields to include in each entry of the bibliography. It seems that the `howpublished` field is not included for manuals.

How about just putting the url in the `note` field, like this:

```
@Manual{XXXX,
title = {Title},
author = {Paul},    
note = {Available at \url{http://www.qqq.com}, version 1.6.0}
}
```

Alternatively, as user Dukeatcoding suggests above, you could use a different bibliography style that supports an `url` field.

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,mybibfile}
```

See: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf

Comment: Alternative would be to change `@Manual` to `@Misc`.