# Why are my biblography/references not showing the URLs

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran, urls

I am using overleaf to write my document. Here is my pre-amble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry} %this is the margin size.
 \setlength {\marginparwidth }{2cm} %confirming the margin width for todonotes?
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{url}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}


\begin{document}
```

Then I want to have the bibliography near the end of my document, so I scroll down to where I want  it, and this is what I have:

```
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\bibliographystyle{ieetr}
\bibliography{bib}
\newpage
%TC:ignore
\begin{appendices}
```

(I want the bibliography to come before the appendices). However, when I compile the document, my references are printed without the url. Here is an example of one of the references I have put into my bib.bib:

```
@article{TLD_variance,
    author={ANDREW MATACZ},
    year={2000},
    month={Jan},
    title={FINANCIAL MODELING AND OPTION THEORY WITH THE TRUNCATED LEVY PROCESS},
    journal={International journal of theoretical and applied finance},
    volume={3},
    number={1},
    pages={143-160},
    abstract={In recent studies the truncated Levy process (TLP) has been shown to be very promising for the modeling of financial dynamics. In contrast to the Levy process, the TLP has finite moments and can account for both the previously observed excess kurtosis at short timescales, along with the slow convergence to Gaussian at longer timescales. In this paper I further test the truncated Levy paradigm using high frequency data from the Australian All Ordinaries share market index. I then consider an optimal option hedging strategy which is appropriate for the early Levy dominated regime. This is compared with the usual delta hedging approach and found to differ significantly.},
    isbn={0219-0249},
    url={http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0219024900000073},
    doi={10.1142/S0219024900000073}
}
```

But when compiled, it is printed like this:

```
[48] A. MATACZ, “Financial modeling and option theory with the truncated levy process,” Interna-
tional journal of theoretical and applied finance, vol. 3, pp. 143–160, Jan 2000.
32
```

How can I get it to also display the url in the reference, and how can I make it so that if someone clicks the reference number in the main text, it will bring them to the specific reference in the bibliography?

Apologies if the code is messy, this is my first time using LaTeX for such a large document.

Comment: That style if very old and does not support the `url` field. If you look in `ieeetr.bst` you'll notice that `url` is not mentioned at all, and thus is just ignored. Note that the style stems from before URLs was even a thing.

Comment: Suggestions in [bibtex display URL in reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117745/106162) are probably the easiest to apply.

Answer (score 2):

You asked,

> how can I make it so that if someone clicks the reference number in the main text, it will bring them to the specific reference in the bibliography?

Be sure to load the `hyperref` package.

> How can I get it to display the `url` field in the reference?

Don't employ the `ieeetr` bib style, which is almost prehistorically old by now and dates back to an age long before URL strings were even conceived of. Instead, I suggest you employ the `IEEEtran` bib style. Its vintage is much more recent than that of `ieeetr`; as a result, it has been programmed to know what to do if an entry has a field called `url`.

By the way, I can see no good reason for ALL-UPPERCASING the contents of the `author` field; hence, please replace `author={ANDREW MATACZ},` with `author = {Andrew Matacz},`. Ditto for the `title` field. I'd further replace `month={Jan},` with `month=jan`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bib.bib}
@article{TLD_variance,
    author   = {Andrew Matacz},
    year     = {2000},
    month    = jan,
    title    = {Financial modeling and option theory with the truncated {Levy} process},
    journal  = {International Journal of Theoretical and Applied Finance},
    volume   = {3},
    number   = {1},
    pages    = {143-160},
    abstract = {...},
    isbn     = {0219-0249},
    url      = {http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0219024900000073},
    doi      = {10.1142/S0219024900000073}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
%%\usepackage{appendix} % don't load packages more than once
%%%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % nooooooo !
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subfig}  % don't load both 'subfig' and 'subcaption' 
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{float} % <-- are you sure?
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm]{geometry} % horizontal margins
\setlength {\marginparwidth }{2cm} %confirming the margin width for todonotes?
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{xurl} % better use 'xurl', not 'url'
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{ragged2e} % <-- new
\frenchspacing % optional

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\RaggedRight
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```