# How to add supporting material link together with cited reference when using bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, formatting, links

I am going to cite a research article which also has useful supporting data by authors in their website.

How can I add the link into Bibtex?

Or do I have to cite the supporting data link as an individual reference?

Comment: You can find some help here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/how-can-i-use-bibtex-to-cite-a-web-page                                                       http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35977/how-to-add-a-url-to-a-latex-bibtex-file

Comment: thank you, the `note={\url{http://...}}` works!