# how add bibliography to a LYX report

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, report

I'm writing my report using LYX . I have to integrate bibliography reference. I would know if there is a package to add.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Basic bibliography:**

1. At the end of your text, select <kbd>Bibliography</kbd> in the left drop down menu.
2. Optional: Click the `key-1[]` gray box to add a label if you want a author-year citation style, as it should be showed (e.g, `Smith, 1981`).
3. Write the full reference after `key-1[]` box.
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to add the next references (`key-2[]`).
5. In the main text, <kbd>Insert</kbd>  > <kbd>Citation ...</kbd>  or go to [image: Citation] in the toolbar and select the reference-s to include.

**BibTeX bibliography (recommended):**

1. List item  <kbd>Insert</kbd>  >  <kbd>List/TOC</kbd> >  <kbd>BibTeX bibliography ...</kbd> .
2. <kbd>Add...</kbd> >  <kbd>Browse</kbd> Add the BibTeX database with the references (external BibTeX files with `.bib` extension): Use a program like JabRef to create/edit  these references. Each reference should have a unique BibTeXkey (e.g, `Smith1981`).
3. Left the style in `plain` at the moment. You can return to this dialog clicking in the generated `BiBTeX Generated Bibliography` gray box.
4. Insert citations exactly as  above (select BibTeXkeys as`Smith1981` in the same way that you select `key-1[]`, `key-2[]`, etc.).
5. Go to  <kbd>Documents</kbd> >  <kbd>Settings ...</kbd> > <kbd>Bibliography</kbd> if you want a author-year style or some others options. This dialog will add packages as `natbib` and the right options when needed.

**Biblatex bibliography**

That is probably the best option for experienced plain LaTeX users, but may be not for new LyX users. But [since versión 2.3.0, Lyx have native support of biblatex](https://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex) in the same menu that above, so simply try it.

Add some biblatex to the preamble is still bit more complex that in plain LaTeX, but it is well explained in the link how to solve this.

Comment: Great , but when i have to add a netography , shall i use the same method. I don't find a URL web site reference key

Comment: @SihemHcine What do you mean? I do not know what type of material could be your reference, but conventional type of publications (e.g. `article`) allow a optional URL field,  and  moreover with Jabref you can add references of type `electronic`, `online`, `www` and  `misc` for less conventional type of publications.

Comment: I mean when i refer to a website(URL) in my report how can i put it as a bibliography. What option should i choose.

Comment: There are not "best option" but @misc entry is could be fine for you. See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35981/11604)I and [here](http://nschloe.blogspot.com.es/2009/06/bibtex-how-to-cite-website_21.html) for some examples of use and more options. Note that you can copy & paste a reference code (i.e., `@misc{...}`) directly  in JabRef  (in the most right tab of the edit window)  for testing  these examples.