# How do I write a formula in words in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, xfrac

I want to write this equation in LaTeX:

[image: q1 = (Number of women who had their second birth in 1971) / ((Number of women who had their first birth in 1970) - (Number of women who had their second birth in 1970))]

This my LaTeX code for the equation:

```
\begin{equation} \nonumber
 q^*_1  =\frac{\text{number of women who had their second birth in 1971}}{\text{number of women who had their first birth in 1970 \textbf{-} number of women had their second birth in 1970}}
  \end {equation}
```

How can write the denominator as given in the picture?

Answer (score 11):

A simple way is to use `array` for the denominator

```
\begin{equation} \nonumber
 q^*_1  =\frac{\text{number of women who had their second birth in 1971}}{
 \begin{array}{c}
   \text{number of women who had}\\
    \text{their first birth in 1970} 
 \end{array}
 -
 \begin{array}{c}
   \text{number of women who had}\\
    \text{their second birth in 1970} 
 \end{array}
 }
  \end{equation}
```

Comment: @statistician,  there is a green check-mark-style button next to the question. And while seems that you tested/prefer/like this answer... you should click this button to accept the answer and to not leave your question be shown as a question that didn't found a good enough answer.

Answer (score 8):

I'd define a suitable notation, avoiding long verbal descriptions. I also added the verbose version, but adding parentheses for clarity.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Let's denote by $W(n,y)$ the number of women who had their $n$th~birth
in the year~$y$. Then
\begin{equation*}
q^*_1 = \frac{W(2,1971)}{W(1,1970)-W(2,1970)}
\end{equation*}
We can also typeset this with words, but it comes out quite awful
unless we add parentheses
\begin{equation*}
q^*_1 =
\frac{
  \text{number of women who had their second birth in 1971}
}{
  \Bigl(
  \begin{tabular}{c}
  number of women who had \\
  their first birth in 1970
  \end{tabular}
  \Bigr)
  -
  \Bigl(
  \begin{tabular}{c}
  number of women who had \\
  their second birth in 1970
  \end{tabular}
  \Bigr)
}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `equation*` avoids the need for `\nonumber`.

Comment: +1. That said, I prefer the verbose version unless you need the values of $W$ often elsewhere. (Differing with @egreg is rare on $\TeX$ SE.)

Answer (score 6):

An approach with `parbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


\begin{equation} \nonumber
 q^*_1  =\frac{\text{number of women who had their second birth in 1971}}{\text{\parbox{4.5cm}{\centering number of women who had their first birth in 1970}} - \text{\parbox{4cm}{\centering number of women had their second birth in 1970}}}
  \end {equation} 

\end{document}
```

Of course the lengths could be different to fit your sizes...

Answer (score 5):

Here is a competety different approach using variables instead of the text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  q^*_1  &=\frac{A}{B-C}  \\
  \text{where}~A &= \text{number of women who had their second birth in 1971} \\
               B &= \text{number of women who had their first birth in 1970} \\
               C &= \text{number of women who had their second birth in 1970} \\
\end{align*}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

For a horizontally centered equation one could use something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  q^*_1  =\frac{A}{B-C} \nonumber
\end{equation} 
\begin{align*}
  \text{where}~A &= \text{number of women who had their second birth in 1971} \\
               B &= \text{number of women who had their first birth in 1970} \\
               C &= \text{number of women who had their second birth in 1970} \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should declare the variables outside the align environment... or add this possibility as separate code in case the the equation should be centered or numbered etc. (+1) -for the answers before and after mine- and (-1) -if I could- to the down-voter who didn't even left a comment to a newcomer that at least provided some code

Comment: @koleygr: Thanks for your suggestion. I have added another suggestion on how to achieve a horizontally centered equation.

Answer (score 5):

Just to throw in an alternative layman's view

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}\huge
$q^*_1 =  \text{number of women who had their (} \frac {2^{nd}\text{ birth in 1971}} {1^{st}\text{ birth in 1970}~-~ 2^{nd}\text{ birth in 1970}}$)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Mathematically the abstraction of 1st birth -2nd berth of a woman are minus the years lived before give a birth! (+1 mostly for the imagination part of your solution)

Comment: @koleygr I'm no mathmagician (only a very very poor TeXnician hence the Layman's tag line

Comment: My comment is just humor since means that a woman's second birth is when she is giving a birth (and these is a sentence with the female psychology of my male nature)... I never heard layman's low before... but thanks for noticing (learned something new). Goodnight and happy TeXing!