# How to add note before URL in a webpage citation?

Tags: bibliographies, url, cite-package

I want to get **online accessed 19-July-2020** before the URL. Currently it's coming after the URL. The MWE is -

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{citekey,
    title = {Road accidents in bangladesh - Wikipedia},
    note = {Online accessed 19-July-2020},
    howpublished =
    {retrieved from: \url {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road{\_}accidents{\_}in{\_}bangladesh}}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}
Example citation \cite{citekey}

\bibliography{mybib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\end{document}
```

Is there any way to define the term **retrieved from:** which I am adding before every url to show it in the reference.  I don't want to write it everytime before every `url` in every `howpublished`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the `IEEEtran` bibliography style, you could make use of the fact that it recognizes a field called `url`.  A happy side-effect of changing the `howpublished` field name to `url` (as well as deleting the "retrieved from:" prefix and removing the `\url{...}` "wrapper") is that the contents of the `note` field will no longer be placed last.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{citekey,
    title = {How to add a {URL} to a {LaTeX} bibtex file},
    note  = {Accessed online 19-July-2020},
    url   = {https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35977/how-to-add-a-url-to-a-latex-bibtex-file}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{cite}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
Example citation \cite{citekey}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for Your reply but I have some problem using `url` instead of `howpublished`. for example this entry `@misc{wiki,
 title = {{Road accidents in bangladesh - Wikipedia}},
 note = {Online accessed 19-July-200},
 howpublished = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road{\_}accidents{\_}in{\_}bangladesh}}` is not working perfectly without `howpublished` -

Comment: @MAzharulIslam - I'm not sure I understand your comment. In my answer, I recommend replacing the `howpublished` field name with `url`.

Comment: If I use `url` fieldname for the above mentioned citation entry it breaks the url.

Comment: @MAzharulIslam - My answer was based on handling the URL `https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35977/how-to-add-a-url-to-a-latex-bibtex-file`, but you're now referring a very different URL. Please edit your original query to provide all relevant information needed to construct the new entry. Please be sure to clarify what the expressions "is not working perfectly" and "it breaks the url" mean. Aside: the URL `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_accidents_in_bangladesh` doesn't seem to point to a real Wikipedia page.