# Links to publications in .bib file get printed as plain text on moderncv

Tags: bibtex, moderncv

My `moderncv`-created resumé compiles without any sort of error: the list of publications regularly appears in its own section, no problems on that side.

However, even though I have inserted the urls of my journal papers in my `.bib` file, publication entries in the resulting pdf document are typed in plain text, devoid of any link.

Links work fine in all other sections of my CV.

`Bibtex` handles my bibliography file.

A MWE:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}  
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{black}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{url}
\setlength{\footskip}{33pt}

\name{I am}{Lingo}
\address{Job title}  % I have put my job title in the address section
\extrainfo{address}  % and my address as extrainfo 
\phone[mobile]{+1(234)567890}                
\email{lingo@lingo.org}

\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={CV}, 
    pdfauthor={Lingo}, 
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=gray,
    urlcolor=gray
}}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Experience}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1}

% other sections

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plainyr}
\bibliography{publications} 

\end{document}
```

and my `publications.bib` file has entries such as

```
@article{Lingo2016,
    title = {A generic {Title}},
    journal = {Yellow Pages},
    url = {\url{https://www.google.com}},
    year = {2016},
    volume = {3},
    pages = {251-266},
    author = {\textbf{Lingo, I A.} and Doe, J.}
}
```

Comment: Looking at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35977/how-to-add-a-url-to-a-latex-bibtex-file I would think it may be a problem with the bibliographystyle. Have you given some others a try?

Comment: Hi @MatthiasArras it doesn't work with the `plain` bibliography style either.

Comment: So you do get the url entry, it's just not a hyperlink?

Comment: I did not get the url entry as well. But going through the link you provided I did as suggested in one of the answers, i.e. to type `note={\url{http://...}}` instead of `url={\url{http://...}}` as I have done above and it works!! Now each publication shows the url in hypertext.

Comment: @MatthiasArras you could expand your comment into an answer and I'd accept it. Also, is there a way to hide the url, which is something like `https://doi.org/10.1016`, and instead directly hyperlink the title of the article?

Comment: I guess, it would make sense to open a new question for that - assuming no answer for it exists already on the platform. Since the provided link contains at least a workaround, I don't think me repeating it adds anything. I still think this can be solved more elegantly, without the need to rewrite all your `url`s as `note`s. But in the meantime, good luck with your job application.

Comment: @MatthiasArras thank you for the good wishes, I'll need all the luck I can get, given the current circumstances. Someone has already asked whether a publication title could be hyperlinked to the url entry in a `bib` file, however he is looking for a solution using `biblatex` https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23832/biblatex-make-title-hyperlink-to-doi-url-if-available while I am using `bibtex`. The solution proposed there is a bit complex because it presupposes all urls being of `doi`-type, but I have also got links to congress sites.