# Make \url{} entry visible in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, url

I'm using a bibliography management software (Zotero) that exports weblinks in this format:

```
@misc{spielmandaniel-DiscrepancyTheoryRandomized-2021,
  title = {But what is the Fourier Transform? A visual introduction.},
  author = {3Blue1Brown},
  year = {2021},
  month = jan,
  url = {https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY},
  urldate = {2021-01-21}
}
```

The issue is now that the bibliography does not show the url:
[image]

I know that there are [fixes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35977/how-to-add-a-url-to-a-latex-bibtex-file) to this by like urls like this

```
howpublished = "\url{http://aiweb.techfak.uni-bielefeld.de/content/bworld-robot-control-software/}"
```

But this is not feasible if your software automatically exports the url as above. But there must be some way to use the above entry with the URL in latex, as zotero exports URLs be default like this. Does anybody know how to make the above @misc entry display also the URL field?

Some details:

- I use Zotero + BetterBibTex, which gives a .bib file with the above entry
- The bibliography is generated via `\bibliographystyle{alpha}`
- I use the url and hyperref packages

Comment: the alpha bibliographystyle is old  and so doesn't support url fields. If you are forced to use it you will have to copy the url in the note or howpublished field. Better would be to switch to a newer style or to biblatex+biber.

Comment: Off-topic: The sample entry you show happens to provide a perfect illustration of why one should never blindly trust information provided by Zotero, Google Books, or any other online source of bibliographic information: Distressingly often, information provided by these sources is just *wrong*. For instance, for the entry at hand, the year field should say `2018`, *not* `2021`, since  the video was posted -- you guessed it -- in `2018`.

Comment: with the BBT zotero plugin you can have that url exported as `url = {...}` by zotero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bibtex, you can use e.g. the `alphaurl` bibliography style (or `plainurl`, etc):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@misc{spielmandaniel-DiscrepancyTheoryRandomized-2021,
  title = {But what is the Fourier Transform? A visual introduction.},
  author = {3Blue1Brown},
  year = {2021},
  month = jan,
  url = {https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY},
  urldate = {2021-01-21}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}


The reference: \cite{spielmandaniel-DiscrepancyTheoryRandomized-2021}


\bibliographystyle{alphaurl}
\bibliography{references}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find the bibliography style `alpha`. But the below code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@misc{spielmandaniel-DiscrepancyTheoryRandomized-2021,
  title = {But what is the Fourier Transform? A visual introduction.},
  author = {3Blue1Brown},
  year = {2021},
  month = jan,
  url = {https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY},
  urldate = {2021-01-21}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex} 
\bibliography{references}

\begin{document}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}

\maketitle

The reference: \cite{spielmandaniel-DiscrepancyTheoryRandomized-2021}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

produces the following result

[image]

on my TeX distribution.

Comment: The `alpha` bibliography style has been around since at least the early 1980s.